# how to pass the data from jsp page(for each) to servlet class

Tags: jsp, servlets, master-detail

I Have JSP code like this. I fetch the Image and data of the product using `forach in one page:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}" >
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <a href="description.html">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.base64EncodedImage}" alt="image">
                    <div class="caption" align="center">
                        <p>
                            <h4>${product.name}</h4>
                            <h5>cost:Rs ${product.price}/-</h5>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of fetched data

[image: Jsp Page output]

Now I have to get the data and image OF PARTICULAR PRODUCT when I click on a tumbnail. I have to get the data in the servlet class and have to print the output in another page:

This is what I expect to see when I click on a thumbnail:

[image: ON THIS PAGE I HAVE TO GET THE DATA WHEN WE HAVE TO CLICK ON TUMBNAIL]

Answer (score 0):

Pass product details to servlet using URL parameters:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${product.base64EncodedImage}" alt="image" href="<your-servlet>?productId=${product.productId}">
```

Retrieve the same in your Product detail servlet class and read the same,passing on the details to the respective page

```
request.getParameter("productId")
```

Comment: thank you for responding.I will try on that.